# Why does this regex miss a single white space between 2 digits?

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I'm trying to find a single white space surrounded by a digit on each side in a string.  I've constructed the following example:

```
library('stringr')
str1 <- "1805.6 1-1 1"
str_locate_all(str1, "\\s+")[[1]]
str_locate_all(str1, "[[:digit:]]\\s[[:digit:]]")[[1]]
```

Which returns:

```
str_locate_all(str1, "\\s+")[[1]]
     start end
[1,]     7   7
[2,]    11  11

str_locate_all(str1, "[[:digit:]]\\s[[:digit:]]")[[1]]
     start end
[1,]     6   8
[2,]    10  12
```

Which is what I expected to see.  Now do the same thing to a different string:

```
str2 <- "1805.6 1 1 1"
str_locate_all(str2, "\\s+")[[1]]
str_locate_all(str2, "[[:digit:]]\\s[[:digit:]]")[[1]]
```

But this seems to miss one of the spaces surrounded by digits (note that the 2nd pattern only returns 2 entries):

```
str_locate_all(str2, "\\s+")[[1]]
     start end
[1,]     7   7
[2,]     9   9
[3,]    11  11

str_locate_all(str2, "[[:digit:]]\\s[[:digit:]]")[[1]]
     start end
[1,]     6   8
[2,]    10  12
```

So the question is, why doesn't the 2nd pattern see the middle white space, and return a row with `8 10` ? I'm sure I'm just not seeing things from `regex`'s way of thinking.

Comment: The matches are consumed. Try a search for overlapping regex http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+overlapping+regex

Comment: I find this output interesting though `str_locate_all(str2, "(?=(\\d\\s\\d))")[[1]]` The end is before the beginning :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your digit after space is consumed after the match. So you are unable to find the match. In your example

Note :- `x` denotes matched digits

```
1805.6 1 1 1
     x^x
      |
   First match

1805.6 1 1 1
        ^
        |
Once the regex engine moves forward, it cannot see backward(unless lookbehind is used).
Here, first digit from regex is matched with space which is not correct so the match fails outright and next position is attempted.

1805.6 1 1 1    
         x^x
         ||Matches digit
         |Matches space
      Matches digit
     (Second match)

This goes on till end of string is reached
```

Visualize here

[image]

You can use `lookahead` instead as

```
> str_locate_all(str1, "\\d\\s(?=\\d)")[[1]]
     start end
[1,]     6   7
[2,]     8   9
[3,]    10  11
```

As lookahaeads are of zero width, we get the position one less than actual ending position.

Comment: Thanks for this clear explanation.  Related question:  Is there a functional difference between using `[[:digit:]]` vs. `\\d`?  Thanks.

Comment: @BryanHanson no i don't think so(till my knowledge)..one thing is there that I had observed is `[[:digit:]]` is supported mostly by DFA engine

Comment: Thanks.  It was on a cheat sheet I had, so I used it.  I will go with the shorter form in the future.